# Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot cannot install

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, usb

So my issue is that for some reason I can't install Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. I downloaded the ISO, extracted it, make a bootable USB, changed the bios to allow USB boot and so on. However when I boot the USB and try to either install or try Ubuntu I get error messages that either just boot me back onto Windows or freeze the screen on the purple Ubuntu page. I am using a Lenovo y700, 16 gigs of ram, Intel 17 and nvidia gtx 960.The error message says something along the lines of

```
nouveau E[ PFIFO][0000:01:00.0] SCHED_ERROR [UNK06]
```

Comment: Did you download the iso from the offical site.? This is a kown bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1514232

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Yes from the official site and i will look into the other forum question to make sure this isnt a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these steps.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation USB media you already have created.

Select (highlight) *Try Ubuntu without installing* and press the E key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line.
Then press the F10 key for booting into the Ubuntu Live desktop.

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>F1</kbd> . Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>F1</kbd>. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS.

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions.

Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs

Comment: I will try this method and get back. But to clarify the issue has to do with my nvidia drivers?

Comment: This will fix your nvidia driver issue

Comment: Sorry to ask but is there any risk in using this method

Comment: No risk and if this doesn't work then you can undo the operation 'sudo apt-get purge nvidia* ; sudo reboot'

Comment: Ok thank you i will go and try this. But when you say login screen do you mean the Ubuntu login screen? Because i have yet to set it up so i dont see how i will have a log in screen yet...

Comment: So i ran into an issue. I can write this in at the end of the linux line nouveau.modeset=0 however right after that i press f10 it takes me to the ubuntu purple load screen and well just freezes...

Comment: @shihab. Is the issue resolved or not? Freezing of the screen might be due to some other issue,,,even a bad or corrupt .iso file.

Comment: I am still trying i just dont understand what you mean by login in screen. I havent installed Ubuntu so i have no login screen.

Comment: what do i do when the screen freezes?

Comment: what was the last action you did which caused screen freezing...try to undo that. Otherwise login to tty(Ctrl+Alt+F1) and go to /var/log directory...you need to go thru log files(dmesg, syslog etc...) to find out what's causing that issue.

Comment: Right after i reinstalled nvidia-361 and rebooted i got past the nouveau error but not say when i am about to install Ubuntu it either freezes on the screen or my mouse stops working completely. Both trackpad and wireless mouse.

Comment: i think im going to just stop trying to install for now since there are obvious issues. First the nouveau error which only gets fixed for a limited time, then the cache data failure , and now the randomly freezing.